# Is dynamic memory access detrimental in real-time programs?

Tags: c++, real-time, heap-memory

I'm working on a project that contains a real-time software component, using the RT PREEMPT patch on Linux.

During "idle" operation the software just sits waiting for incoming TCP connections and requests. Depending on the request, the software may create a real-time thread that runs for a period of time. So the entire application doesn't need to operate in real-time, only this one thread from time to time.

My question is this: I'm well aware that dynamic memory allocation is non-deterministic and is detrimental to real-time code. However, is accessing existing memory on the heap also detrimental to real-time constraints?

I ask because I'm considering a situation where the program starts up, allocates any required structures on the heap, then triggers a real-time thread that accesses the heap.

EDIT: Once the real-time thread has started, other threads are prevented from writing to variables the real-time thread needs to access using locks (well, except for one variable that must be updated, but access is still restricted using a separate lock).

EDIT2: I forgot to mention that the program will ultimately be deployed on a system that doesn't have any swap space, so I don't think the paging of memory should be an issue. (Though of course this doesn't avoid the issue of page-faults through memory that hasn't yet been provisioned by the OS.)

Comment: What if you have several requests? Are you sure that only one single "real-time" thread can run?

Comment: Yes it's straightforward to add an atomic flag that indicates whether the real-time thread is already running. If it is, a second one isn't started.

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation is _not guaranteed to be_ deterministic. There are allocation algorithms which are deterministic. Probably the best known is a stack (in the data structure sense of the word, not the call stack). It obviously suffers from the fact that freeing memory below the top of stack does not make that memory immediately reusable, but allocation is O(1) always.

Comment: what do you mean by accessing? is read or is it write? because when it's write, accessing this memory from more than one thread will kill the performance.

Comment: Once the real-time thread has started, other threads are prevented from writing to variables the real-time thread needs to access using locks (well, except for one variable that must be updated, but access is still restricted using a separate lock).

Comment: it's not about synchronising. you could have as well separate indexes of array accessed by each thread (no synch needed). the point is that page which holds changed variable is marked as dirty after any write to this variable and has to be refetched by every other thread.

Comment: Okay I see. I'll check my code, but I don't think I have a situation like that. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @orentaga: don't comment your own question, but **edit that question** to improve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is accessing existing memory on the heap also detrimental to real-time constraints?

No, unless your system is [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)).

BTW, you could consider writing your own allocation (e.g. above [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)...) and using [mlock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html) for the memory that ought to be in RAM.

Comment: No, thrashing is a full-system thing.

Comment: Although it won't hurt, it's not really necessary to use `mmap()`.   It is necessary to determine, through analysis, that the system has sufficient memory so the allocated memory CAN remain in RAM i.e. that `mlock()` will not fail.   That will normally amount to only allocating memory dynamically at startup (so the amount of memory allocated is pre-determined) , avoiding techniques that consume unlimited stack (e.g. avoid recursion and explicitly use alternatives, such as iteration), and ensuring the host has enough RAM to accommodate all memory (whether dynamically allocated or not).

Comment: Thanks Basile. Could you elaborate? Do you mean writing a separate `operator new`? Or perhaps a custom allocator for use by STL objects?

Comment: Both, I don't know what you are coding. And I don't know how real-time or critical is your application.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the virtual memory manager might move your memory to swap making your thread generate a major page fault when it runs. You need to lock the memory pages using mlock(). I also recommend allocating memory in chunks and writing to all of it with memset() before using it to avoid minor page faults at run time and use placement new instead of the regular one to create your objects in the already allocated memory.